# remove object from string with mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I have the following string and I need to remove the boom property and value using mysql command

```
{"test4":["ip","userAgent"],"monitoringMode":{"isMonitoring":false,"dates":null},"test55":{"test2":[{"active":1,"pixelId":"AW-123123123"}]},"boom":["G-bbb","G-213232"],"test1":[{"aaa":"UA-123","dimensionIndex":"dimension123"}]}
```

desired result

```
{"test4":["ip","userAgent"],"monitoringMode":{"isMonitoring":false,"dates":null},"test55":{"test2":[{"active":1,"pixelId":"AW-123123123"}]},"test1":[{"aaa":"UA-123","dimensionIndex":"dimension123"}]}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why is this tagged with PostgreSQL?

Comment: Also - what is precise MySQL version?

Comment: I might need to use the command with postgres as well

Comment: Which database are you actually using? PostgreSQL and MySQL are completely different products with different features. JSON handling isn't part of the SQL standard and each database has its own methods and features

Comment: `I might need to use the command with postgres as well` that's not possible. JSON isn't part of SQL. Each database has its own custom support for it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: "*JSON handling isn't part of the SQL standard*" - it actually is.

Comment: If you want to reuse the functionality, build it into your application, not into any query

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you're right. But it seems PostgreSQL doesn't follow it. I really hate having to pay to just read the SQL standard docs

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: there were plans for Postgres 15 to support the SQL:2016 JSON functions. But that had to be removed due to implementation issues.  But it _seems_ that's going to make it to Postgres 16. Some parets of the standard are available online though, e.g. here. https://jakewheat.github.io/sql-overview/

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name two reasons I hate not being able to read the standard for free: 1) I can't complain about how far SQL Server has fallen behind 2) I keep getting surprised by features I thought would exist in PostgreSQL but don't.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: as far as I can tell, Postgres supports all JSON _features_ from the SQL standard, just not with the same syntax.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name if the syntax isn't the same, or, in this case, completely different, you can't use the same SQL query across databases. But that's just how SQL works - features are standardized years after products implement them. And no database could wait for 3-4 years for JSON support to get finalized. For temporal tables it's closer to a decade

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data is stored in a column within a table:

MySQL (8) see [this ref](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-functions.html):

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column_name = JSON_REMOVE(column_name, '$.boom')
WHERE condition;
```

see this [MySQL fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kmvXfAfB)

For Postgres (recent versions) the equivalent would be, assuming the column data type is `jsonb`:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column_name = column_name - 'boom'
WHERE condition;
```

As you can see in this simple example that the syntax is not common across dbms.,

---

From the additional information that the Postgres column is varchar: Convert to jsonb, use json methods to manipulate, then convert back to varchar. e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
    id serial primary key,
    column_name varchar(200)
);

INSERT INTO table_name (column_name)
VALUES ('{"boom": "goes the dynamite", "foo": "bar", "number": 42}');
```

```
select * from table_name
```

| id | column_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"boom": "goes the dynamite", "foo": "bar", "number": 42} |

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column_name = (column_name::jsonb - 'boom')::text
WHERE 1=1;
```

```
select * from table_name
```

| id | column_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"foo": "bar", "number": 42} |

See this [Postgres fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/CDmQmSgf)

Comment: thanks for postgress the type is character varying
the script metioned does not work

Comment: It does not work directly on a varchar column - that is why the data type is specified in my answer. There are many very good reasons for using special data types for JSON. If you simply use varchar then you must use generic text manipulation functions. ps, it is necessary to include relevant facts in your question if you expect precise answers